# How to get all images from value of the input using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core

I am using [Summernote](https://summernote.org/) text editor for getting input from user i.e i am getting HTML back
from the user.Now i want to get all images that user give and store them in file.
Here's my jquery code:

The value variable contain the html user is giving.

I want to know what must be the next step i.e i want to get all images from the value variable using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qsform').on('submit', function () {

        var value = $('#summernote').val();
        var images = value.$('img');
        var srcList = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            srcList.push(images[i].src);
        }
        alert(srcList)
    })
});
```

and here's my .cshtml file:

```
@model QuoraForPucit.Models.Question
@{       
    ViewData["Title"] = "Ask Question";
}
@section links{
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/AskQs.css")"/>
    <script defer src="~/js/askqs.js"></script>
}
<div asp-validation-summary="All" role="alert" style=""></div>
<div class="qs-container mt-5 mb-5 py-5">
        <h1>Ask a Public Question</h1>
        <form id="qsform"  method="post" action="/User/AskQuestion" class="d-flex justify-content-space-between align-items-center" style="flex-direction: column;">
            <div class="title-div">
                <label asp-for="Title">Question Title:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" asp-for="Title" id="title1">
                <br>
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="qs-div">
                <label asp-for="Description">Description:</label>
                <br>
                <textarea asp-for="Description" id="summernote"></textarea>
                <br>
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="opt-grp">
                <label asp-for="Subject">Choose Subject:</label>
                <br>
                <select asp-for="Subject" id="subject">
                    <option selected="selected" value="Exam">Exam</option>
                    <option value="Admission">Admission</option>
                    <option value="Job">Job</option>
                    <option value="Study">Study</option>
                    <option value="Information">Information</option>
                    <option value="Information">Information</option>
                    <option value="Events">Events</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success submit-btn" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
              $('#summernote').summernote({
        placeholder: 'Description goes here....',
        height:'25vh',
        toolbar: [
          ['style', ['style']],
          ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
          ['color', ['color']],
          ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
          ['table', ['table']],
          ['insert', ['link', 'picture']],
          ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
        ]
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: None of the code makes much sense. What kind of object is `value` if not a string and then what is `var images = value.$('img');` supposed to do? Please post a runnable example with libraries

Comment: @mplungjan I edited my question hope you can understand it now :(

Comment: Please do as I suggested. Make the snippet runnable and remove all cshtml

Comment: Hi @UsmanArshad, what do you mean to get the value, what's you scenario to get the image to do? If you just want to get the src, you can check the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the images src by:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qsform').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var srcList = [];
        var rawHtml = $($('#summernote').summernote('code'));
            rawHtml.find('img').each(function (i,data) {
                srcList.push(data.src)
            });
        //do your stuff...
                
    })
});
```